# Chroot into Arch Bootable USB

Tags: usb, arch-linux, bootable-media, chroot

I have a bootable USB drive with Arch Linux recently installed on it (Linux kernel 3.19.2). I want to plug it in to my computer and `chroot` into it (or possibly run it inside a container, using `systemd-nspawn` or something similar), giving me an Arch environment without having to reboot (and also because one of the machines can't boot from USB drives).

If I'm not mistaken, for `chroot`ing I will have to mount (sometimes recursively) `dev`, `sys`, `proc`, `tmp`, etc. from the running system on to the filesystem on the USB drive, right? When I try, I am never able to unmount them properly. Also, my system (Fedora 17) gives unexpected glitches when I mount these directories: file browser hangs inside the USB drive mount directory, terminal refuses to open, a whole bunch of system notifications about "new device found", and so on.

The container approach, too, is currently not working for me. I am using `systemd-nspawn`, which can give me just a shell, but when I try to 'boot' the system, it goes into a loop waiting for D-Bus and becomes unresponsive.

How do I correctly use the system on a bootable USB drive with Arch within a host system? Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Not quite sure If I unserstand your question. But `mount /dev/your_partition /mnt` and `arch-chroot /mnt` should do what you want I think.

Comment: @TomTom But then the `/dev`, `/sys`, etc. directories on the USB drive are empty

Answer (score 0):

Look into **arch-chroot** script. It takes care of /proc /sys /dev asf.. It's probably your solution.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you think it is the correct solution?